# How to give a child element a higher z-index than the parent element

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've run into a small problem with z-indexing.

I have a header and inside that a link.
The header has a z-index of 5, and the link has a z-index of 15.
When I open up a modal, the dark overlay should be above the header, so I gave it a z-index of 10.
The problem is that the link within the header should be above the overlay, but it's behind it.
I've even given the link a position of relative, but it does nothing.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

`z-index` is relative to the siblings within the same parent. you will have to take the `<a>` out of the `<header>` to create the desired effect.

If the parent has lower `z-index` than the modal, everything in it will be behind the modal, regardless of the children's `z-index`

Please also attach a jsFiddle or something so we can show you how to fix this.

Comment: Not if you keep it inside the parent with the lower `z-index`. However this reminds me of a plugin a came across some time ago.. [jQuery tools expose](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/toolbox/expose.html) which might save you some time..

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ever has this problem, here's a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/flobar/r6zeoc0y/

What I did was I used the `header` as a container. I then seperated the elements that needed to be below and above the overlay into seperate `div`'s with different `z-index`. I also used `position: absolute;` to position them correctly within the `header`. Like so you don't run into the issue of the children inheriting the parent's z-index.

Answer (score -1):

You can give the parent DIV z-index: inherit and  your a element inside the parent div. z-index higher then the overlay.